# Python un-understandable flow control

Tags: python, python-3.3, control-flow

I'm a newbie in Python and its my day 3 in it. I am just warming up some syntax of python with this following ugly example.

```
networks = {"Ufone": 333, "Mobilink": 300, "Warid": 321}

def get_network(n):
    for network in networks:
        if n == networks[network]:
            return "Network is " + str(network)
        else:
            return "Network not listed"

print(get_network(321))
```

You know that it should result `Network is Warid` **But** when I run the script in Sublime Console using `Ctrl + B` sometimes it results..

`Network is Warid
[Finished in 0.1s]`

and other times..

`Network not listed
[Finished in 0.1s]`

and I myself know that I didn't change any value in the function arguments. Its the first time I'm facing this funny problem in programming.

Comment: It always says `Network is Warid
[Finished in 0.0s]` on mine.

Comment: @thefourtheye: In Python 3.3, with hash randomization, the dictionary order can differ between runs. So, entirely randomly, `Ufone` can be listed first and not match.

Comment: @thefourtheye Add your comment line in answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh yeah. I just realized my Sublime uses Python 2.7.

Answer (score 6):

Your loop doesn't do much looping. You return after testing only the *first* entry.

Move the second `return` *out* of the loop:

```
def get_network(n):
    for network in networks:
        if n == networks[network]:
            return "Network is " + str(network)

    return "Network not listed"
```

Now you loop until you find a matching network, and only if you tested all entries, and no match was found do you return with `Network not listed`.

Comment: Also, it would make sense to iterate over the dict using `items()`/`iteritems()`.

Comment: @Esenti: Sure, but that's not the issue here; the OP is 3 days into learning Python; overwhelming them with more detail is not going to help, necessarily.